# convert text file to xml tags format using batch script

Tags: batch-file, scripting

I have below a text file with below content.

```
U    /modules/configuration/gsrc/util/CoverageValidation.gs

C    /modules/configuration/gsrc/util/CoverageForm.gs

D    /modules/configuration/gsrc/util/Trigger.gs

A    /modules/configuration/gsrc/util/Trigger-join.gs
```

My script is this:

```batch
@echo off
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

    set file=test.txt
    set update_tag=<action>Updated</action>
    set add_tag=<action>Added</action>
    set conflict_tag=<action>Conflicted</action>
    set delete_tag=<action>Deleted</action>
    if exist !file! (
        echo The file exists.
        for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in (!file!) do (
            set line=%%a
            if !line! equ "U    " (
                set line=~0,5=!update_tag!!
            )else if !line! equ "A    " (
                set line=~0,5=!add_tag!!
            )else if !line! equ "C    " (
                set line=~0,5=!conflict_tag!!
            )else if !line! equ "D    " (
                set line=~0,5=!delete_tag!!
            )
        )
    ) else (
        echo The file doesn't exist.
    )
endlocal
```

Now I need this text file convert like below format using Batch script.

```xml
<action>Updated</action>

<path>/modules/configuration/gsrc/util/CoverageValidation.gs</path>

<action>Conflicted</action>

<path>/modules/configuration/gsrc/util/CoverageForm.gs</path>

<action>Deleted</action>

<path>/modules/configuration/gsrc/util/Trigger.gs</path>

<action>Added</action>

<path>/modules/configuration/gsrc/util/Trigger-join.gs</path>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
type file.txt |repl "^U " "Updated\r\n\r\n" x|repl "^C " "Conflicted\r\n\r\n" x|repl "^D " "Deleted\r\n\r\n" x|repl "^A " "Added\r\n\r\n" x >file2.txt
```

This uses a helper batch file called `repl.bat` (by dbenham) - download from:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/qidqwztmetbvklt/repl.bat

Place `repl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file or in a folder that is on the path.